# Call HidDevice.FromIdAsync in UWP APP, using ReadWrite will returns null, while using Read will returns HidDevice

Tags: c#, xml, uwp, hid

First of all, I can confirm that this hid device can be read & write in WinForm.
Here is my uwp code:

```
var myDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync("System.Devices.InterfaceEnabled:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True AND System.DeviceInterface.Hid.VendorId:=3800 AND System.DeviceInterface.Hid.ProductId:=300");
//i try to using HidDevice.GetDeviceSelector(0x0001, 0x0005) but get a empty collection
if (myDevices.Any())
{
    //readwriteDevice will be null
    var readwriteDevice = await HidDevice.FromIdAsync(myDevices[0].Id, FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

    //readonlyDevice will be HidDevice
    var readonlyDevice = await HidDevice.FromIdAsync(myDevices[0].Id, FileAccessMode.Read);
    Debug.WriteLine($"UsageId: {readonlylDevice.UsageId}, UsagePage: {readonlylDevice.UsagePage}");//UsageId: 5, UsagePage: 1


    var information= DeviceAccessInformation.CreateFromId(myDevices[0].Id);
    Debug.WriteLine($"CurrentStatus: {information.CurrentStatus}");//Allowed
}
```

Besides, I'm already here Package.appxmanifest The following is defined:

```
<DeviceCapability Name="humaninterfacedevice">
    <Device Id="vidpid:0ED8 012C">
        <Function Type="usage:0001 0005" />
    </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

So I don't know what the problem is. Is there any place where you can define read and write permissions?

Comment: Could you share more info about your hid device info and the app's target version and min version. And could you try to use other Function Type value to test?

Comment: And please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.humaninterfacedevice?view=winrt-19041) here to chose the correct usage

Comment: Read/Write access of the device depends on the device.  There is a device standard that defines header (properties) and the Read/Write is not a property in the header.  The drivers of the device may only allow reading or writing of the device and access to the property depends on the vendor unique properties.  So device types like a File System do have Read/Write permissions of files on the drive.